VsCode ignores JSON indentation settings for tasks.json, settings.json etc
I added a tasks.json file in the local .vscode directory, but it got indented 4 spaces. I want 2 spaces, obviously. So then I followed the advice in this post and this post, ultimately arriving at the file .vscode/settings.json looking as follows
{
    "[json]": {
        "editor.detectIndentation": false,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
    }
}

But the indentation persisted.
After several hours I managed to narrow it down to the filename. If I add a .json file with a random name, the setting is respected and it indents 2 spaces, but if the file is named settings.json or tasks.json, the setting goes ignored, irrespective of the location of the file. For instance, a file named tasks2.json will get indented properly.
This is a new installation of VsCode, with no JSON extensions installed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The language for those files is jsonc (JSON with comments). Your language scope should therefore be [jsonc] instead of [json]

Doesn't work either.

@Dino no repro. works fine for me.
